# Block .config files from showing up in pending changes in Visual Studio 2015 (\w VSO)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops, nant

I'm using Nant to generate my web.config files on building my projects. This means that every developer in the team, automatically generates their web.config files based on templates.

The result is dat everytime someone builds the generated web.config shows up as a pending change. Previously we would delete the web.config from our TFS (visual studio online hosted) server, so source control wouldn't consider the web.config a file that needs checkin-in. However, since we now need the web.configs in source control for a successfull build (it wasn't building on the server before), the web.configs are required again.

Tried:

- .tfignore, doesn't work if the web.config is in source control.
- cloaking in TFS, only works on folders, not seperate items
- local workspace cloaking, now this works..but it would require every developer to manually configure/cloak a lot of files, which is very unpractical.
- Keeping the generated configs in the Excluded changes, this works, but its very messy and easy to get wrong with other exluded changes.
- Setting permissions, didn't do anything.

Comment: The typical way is to have template files committed to source control, with template-related names, and then on local build copy and fixup the actual config files, this way you can safely commit template changes to source control and ignore the actual config files. It is not possible to get the source control tool to count relevant changes and ignore irrelevant changes, to the same file, since it doesn't know what is relevant or irrelevant to begin with.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that since the generated web.config's are defined the project-definition-file the build server will look for them. Using a solution like the .tfignore would work...but doesn't because it requires the specific file to not be in source control.

Comment: You would change your build script to perform the same local production of the config files.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll look into that.

Comment: @user2713516 Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the issue has been put on hold for a bit, I'll try out the options given and update this issue when its done :)

Answer (score 0):

The other way:

1. Put config file in a folder of the project and add to source control
2. Ignore actual config files
3. Add Copy files build step (before VS build step) to the build definition to copy config file (in that folder) to corresponding folder